# R shiny bigger window

Tags: r, shiny

Can you guys help me, how not to need to scroll, or make the window of the application bigger, so you can see the slider bars and plots at once? Or that slidebar and the plot will be side by side.[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV8n1.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
library(deSolve)
library(shiny)


ui <- verticalLayout(

  titlePanel("Zvolte údaje"),


  sliderInput(inputId = "time_values", label = "Počet dnů", value = 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  sliderInput(inputId = "beta", label ="Míra nákazy", value = 0.05, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01),
  sliderInput(inputId = "gamma", label ="Míra uzdravení", value = 0.5, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1),


  (plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
    with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
      dS <- -beta * I * S
      dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
      dR <-  gamma * I
      return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
    })
  }

  initial_values <-  c(S = 1000, I = 1, R = 0)

  sir_values_1 <- reactiveValues(val = data.frame())

  observe({
    sir_values_1$val <- as.data.frame(ode(
      y = initial_values,
      times = seq(0, input$time_values),
      func = sir_equations,
      parms = c(beta=input$beta, gamma=input$gamma) 
    ))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    with(sir_values_1$val, {
    plot(sir_values_1$val$time, sir_values_1$val$S, type = "l", col = "blue",
         xlab = "Doba (dny)", ylab = "Počet lidí")
    lines(sir_values_1$val$time, sir_values_1$val$I, col = "red")
    lines(sir_values_1$val$time, sir_values_1$val$R, col = "green")
    legend("right", c("zdraví", "nakažení", "uzdravení"),
           col = c("blue", "red", "green"), lty = 1, bty = "n")
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you

Comment: have a look at the basic examples https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/ - loads of them have the inputs and plot side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `verticalLayout()` but if you use `fluidPage()` you can achieve this result.

I also simplified your code to an example everyone can run. You'll receive more help when you simplify your code as much as possible; remove as many libraries as you can, simplify your data set and reactive values, etc.

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Zvolte údaje"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins", label = "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      sliderInput(inputId = "beta", label ="Slider 2", value = 0.05, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      sliderInput(inputId = "gamma", label ="Slider 3", value = 0.5, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1)
    ),
    column(width = 8,
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```